# Odoo 10 - Account move line import

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In Odoo 8, we could import CSV data for "Account moves" and "Account move lines".

I'm migrating to Odoo 10 : i found how to import "Account moves" but where can i import the line of my moves (there's no "Import" button on the view of Account move lines) ?

Thanx.

Christophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **account.move.line** default tree view **create='false'** is set.

If in tree view **create='false'** is set  then odoo will hide **Create** and **Import** button.

The following is **odoo default view**.

```
    <record id="view_move_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.move.line.tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.move.line</field>
        <field eval="1" name="priority"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Journal Items" create="false">
                <field name="date"/>
                <field name="move_id" required="0"/>
                <field name="journal_id" options='{"no_open":True}'/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="ref"/>
                <field name="statement_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="partner_id"/>
                <field name="account_id" options='{"no_open":True}' domain="[('company_id', '=', company_id)]"/>
                <field name="analytic_account_id" groups="analytic.group_analytic_accounting"/>
                <field name="reconciled" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="full_reconcile_id"/>
                <field name="debit" sum="Total Debit"/>
                <field name="credit" sum="Total Credit"/>
                <field name="amount_currency" readonly="True" groups="base.group_multi_currency"/>
                <field name="currency_id" readonly="True" invisible="1" />
                <field name="date_maturity"/>
                <field name="company_currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

You can override above Tree view in your module and remove **create='false'**.

```
    <record id="account.view_move_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.move.line.tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.move.line</field>
        <field eval="1" name="priority"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Journal Items">
                <field name="date"/>
                <field name="move_id" required="0"/>
                <field name="journal_id" options='{"no_open":True}'/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="ref"/>
                <field name="statement_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="partner_id"/>
                <field name="account_id" options='{"no_open":True}' domain="[('company_id', '=', company_id)]"/>
                <field name="analytic_account_id" groups="analytic.group_analytic_accounting"/>
                <field name="reconciled" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="full_reconcile_id"/>
                <field name="debit" sum="Total Debit"/>
                <field name="credit" sum="Total Credit"/>
                <field name="amount_currency" readonly="True" groups="base.group_multi_currency"/>
                <field name="currency_id" readonly="True" invisible="1" />
                <field name="date_maturity"/>
                <field name="company_currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

After that You can import CSV file.

You can import account.move.line & account.move in same file, I have attached import format.

[image]
You can export any existing account move from Action in tree view and select all required field.Just export it.

If you want to import account.move.line and account.move using different file then you must inherit account.move.line create method and set check_move_validity is False.

```
    if self._context.get('check_move_validity', True):
        move.with_context(context)._post_validate()
```

Above condition is odoo base module account.move.line create method condtion.When account.move.line is create at that time system is checking if check_move_validity is False then system will not try to reconcile single move line.

You need to inherit create and write method in custom module,after that line by line import work as well.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    move_line = super(AccountMoveLine, self.with_context(check_move_validity=False)).create(vals)
    return move_line

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    move_line = super(AccountMoveLine, self.with_context(check_move_validity=False)).write(vals)
    return move_line
```

This may help you.

Comment: I try this solution and yes, i was happy to see the "Import" button appears! But unfortunatly, when i want to import some move lines (well balanced), Odoo said it can't import the first line because it is unbalanced! (obviously, Odoo check line by line instead of all lines of a movement only).

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can try using different wayl.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution !

Answer (score 0):

for information i am on odoov11.0c
all is based on ids,when you import data  remember that account_account account_move and account_move_line are linked and see terms used directly on model class

from an xls files you can import from the standard menu account_move and account move line using those first line cells name:
    Journal
    Date
    id
    line_ids/partner_id
    Number
    reference
    line_ids/debit
    line_ids/credit 
    narration
    line_ids/matching_number/Number
    line_ids/due date
     line_ids/counterpart
    line_ids/account_id 
    Status

Hope this help